# Unix Find files for specific time duration

Tags: linux, unix

I have a case where I want to dynamically find files for past 24hrs but not from current timestamp. To explain with eg:
Suppose current time is 10.00AM then I want to list the files from 6AM current day to 6AM prev day ie go back 4hrs from current time and then look for 24hrs.
I am looking this for unix system

Answer (score 2):

`find` supports logic operators. You can use those to search for a range. Also, `find`, by default, searches in 24 hours granularity, but it does have the `-newer` option which is more precise.

My solution is as follows:

- Create a file with the timestamp of the latest point in the range
- Create a file with the timestamp of the earliest point in the range
- Search for files newer than the second file, but not newer than the first one.

In bourne shell:

```
END=`date -d 6:00 +%s` # Get time of 6:00am in seconds since epoch
touch late -d "@$END"
START=$(($END-60*60*24)) # Subtract 24 hours
touch early -d "@$START"
find / -newer early -a -not -newer late
```